# Regex that handles paired escaping brackets

Tags: regex

Here is the situation, I need to match a string that

1) starts with a '$' and ends with a '$';

2) there is no '$' in-between, except for being escaped by pairs of brackets '{', '}';

3) there can be nested brackets, and every left bracket must have a matched right bracket.

4) the string can have multiple lines.

For example,

Valid:

> $1,2,3,4,5,6$
>
> $ { $ 1,2,3} $ // the middle '$' is escaped by the brackets
>
> $ { {$  {1,2},3 }  } $
>
> $ { {$  {1,2}\r\n,3 }\r\n  } $ // multiple lines

Invalid:

> $ 1,2$ $
>
> $ {1,2 $ // if there is any bracket, they must match
>
> $ {1,2,$,3},4 $ // the middle '$' is not escaped by a pair of brackets
>
> $ {$} { 1,2 {} $

This looks rather complicated. I have an initial solution which seems to work for 1), 2) and 4), but it cannot check if every left bracket '{' has a correct right bracket '}'.

`\$(([^\$]*(\{[\s\S]+\})+[^\$]*)|([^\$]+))\$`

Comment: `there can be nested brackets` ... regex is suitable for all of your requirements except for this one.  You probably will need to write some sort of parser to handle this.

Comment: Requirement (3) can probably be met by balancing groups - see, e.g. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups for more. However, this feature may not supported by all regex flavors.

Comment: Just use a `stack` to do this! You put on the stack the opening `brackets`, ignore the escaped `$` if the top of the stack is an opening bracket,otherwise throw an error.  When you reach a closing bracket you pop it. At the end of the processing if your stack is not empty it means that your string is not well-formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified which language you are using I have implemented a working prototype using `java`.

As [**tim**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) has mentioned in his comment, Regex are not the proper tool when it comes nested patterns. In order to solve, your problem you can use the following approach in one pass:

- Do some basic checks on the size of the string and that it starts/ends with a `$`
- Read the string character by character (ignore the extremities) and check that for each `$` the preceding character is an `{`
- Use a stack to push and pop the `{`, `}` if the stack is empty and you want to pop a `{` this means that the string is not well-formed at the end of the processing you should have an empty stack

**SAMPLE:**

```
    public static boolean stringBracketsValidator(String input)
    {
        //enforce the constraint that the string is not null, its length is at least 2
        if(input == null || input.length() < 2)
            return false;
        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
        //starts and ends with $ constraint
        if(charArray[0]!= '$' || charArray[charArray.length-1] != '$')
            return false;
        //stack  to validate the nesting and the $ proper escape
        Stack<Character> bracketNestingValidator = new Stack<Character>();
        //we are not processing the extrimities of the char array
        for(int i = 1; i < charArray.length-1; i++)
        {
            /*while reading the input string if we reach a dollar character
             * we check that it is preceded by an opening bracket
             */
            if(charArray[i] == '$')
                if(charArray[i-1] != '{')
                    return false;
            //when we reach an opening bracket we put it on the stack 
            if(charArray[i] == '{')
                bracketNestingValidator.push('{');
            //when we reach a closing bracket we check that the stack is not empty
            if(charArray[i] == '}')
                if(bracketNestingValidator.size() == 0 )
                    return false;
                else
                    bracketNestingValidator.pop();//we pop the opening bracket we have pushed on the stack
        }

        //check that the stack is empty at the end of the run
        if(bracketNestingValidator.size() == 0)
            return true;
        return false;

    }
```

**INPUT:**

```
System.out.println("$1,2,3,4,5,6$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$1,2,3,4,5,6$"));
System.out.println("null string: "+stringBracketsValidator(null));
System.out.println("empty string: "+stringBracketsValidator(""));
System.out.println("1-sized string: "+stringBracketsValidator("1"));
System.out.println("2-sized string: "+stringBracketsValidator("11"));
System.out.println("$$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$$"));
System.out.println("${$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${$"));
System.out.println("${}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${}$"));
System.out.println("${$}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${$}$"));
System.out.println("${$$}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${$$}$"));
System.out.println("${${$}}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${${$}}$"));
System.out.println("${$1,2,3}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${$1,2,3}$"));
System.out.println("${{${1,2}\r\n,3}\r\n }$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("${{${1,2}\r\n,3}\r\n }$"));

System.out.println("$ 1,2$ $ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$ 1,2$ $"));
System.out.println("$ {1,2 $ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$ {1,2 $"));
System.out.println("$ {1,2 }}$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$ {1,2 }}$"));
System.out.println("$}1,2$ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$}1,2$"));
System.out.println("$ {1,2,$,3},4 $ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$ {1,2,$,3},4 $"));  
System.out.println("$ {$} { 1,2 {} $ string: "+stringBracketsValidator("$ {$} { 1,2 {} $"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$1,2,3,4,5,6$ string: true
null string: false
empty string: false
1-sized string: false
2-sized string: false
$$ string: true
${$ string: false
${}$ string: true
${$}$ string: true
${$$}$ string: false
${${$}}$ string: true
${$1,2,3}$ string: true
${{${1,2}
,3}
 }$ string: true
$ 1,2$ $ string: false
$ {1,2 $ string: false
$ {1,2 }}$ string: false
$}1,2$ string: false
$ {1,2,$,3},4 $ string: false
$ {$} { 1,2 {} $ string: false
```

Comment: Although this does not solve my problem (my situation restricts we either use regex or nothing), I upvote it to appreicate & respect your effort for all the coding and test. If in a week there is no other answer coming up (very likely, we have realized regex may not have the power to match quotes or brackets), I will tick your answer